# Connecting to IAP (Identity Aware Proxy) protected service with PHP and Service Account

Tags: php, service-accounts, google-iap

How to connect to an IAP protected service with PHP via Service Account? I already fail to get the Authentication Bearer, so I guess I'm completely on the wrong track:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam'];

$client = new Google_Client;
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes($scopes);
$client->setSubject('example@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com');
$client->setOpenidRealm('https://example.com');
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();

var_dump($access_token);
```

Any pointer to where and how to start would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto ?  Unfortunately we don't have sample code for PHP yet, but that explains the basic concepts. The "Robot Parade" section of https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/04/Getting-started-with-Cloud-Identity-Aware-Proxy.html may be helpful as well.

Unfortunately, IAP doesn't support access tokens for authentication, so you're going to need to get a service-account-signed JWT, and it needs to have a special "target_audience" claim.  Is $client->config['signing_key'] set? If so, you have access to the service account's private key, and can... take a look at https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-php/blob/master/src/OAuth2.php#L417 and if you can get the credentials object you can do something like that, add the target_audience claim.

If you *don't* have access to the private key, which I think is only the case if you're running on GCE and using a service account from the metadata server, you'll have to use the IAM signBlob API: https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob .  This requires some tricky setup on the GCE instance, https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto documents it.

Sorry, I know this is all more complicated than it should be! I'm not a PHP expert, but I hope this at least helps.
  -- Matthew, Identity-Aware Proxy engineer